# Jersey - The servlet context path and/or the servlet path contain characters that are percent encoded

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am using Jersey and Tomcat and I am getting the following message whenever I click a link:

```
HTTP Status 500 - The servlet context path and/or the servlet path contain
characters that are percent encoded

type: Exception report

message: The servlet context path and/or the servlet path contain characters
         that are percent encoded

description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
             fulfilling this request.

exception:
    javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: The servlet context path and/or the servlet path
    contain characters that are percent encoded
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
      logs.
```

The path to the REST service is:

```
http://localhost:8070/simple-service-webapp/rest/hello
```

When I type this into the URL bar it works, but when I click on a link somewhere on the way the URL becomes this:

```
http://localhost:8070/simple%2Dservice%2Dwebapp/rest/hello
```

And somehow Jersey does not deal with percent encoded URLs by default.

Can someone please help me get this to work without removing the dash in the URL? My search did not provide a working solution.

### Listings

**HelloResource.java**

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHelloPlainText(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        String name = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("name");

        if (name == null) {
            name = "unknown user";
        }

        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHelloHtml(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        String text = sayHelloPlainText(uriInfo);

        String result = "<html>" + "<head>" + "<title>Hello Jersey</title>" + "</head>"
                      + "<body>" + "<h1>" + text + "</h1>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

        return result;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayHelloXml(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        String text = sayHelloPlainText(uriInfo);

        String result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello>Hello " + text + "!" + "</hello>";

        return result;
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>RESTful Web Application</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>My RESTful Web Application!</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="rest/hello">Hello from Jersey</a></li>
        <li><a href="rest/hello?name=Johannes">Hello using parameters</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-service-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simple-service-webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>simple-service-webapp</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>

                <inherited>true</inherited>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>

                <configuration>
                    <id>WildFlyServer</id>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>

                <configuration>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>

                    <url>http://localhost:8070/manager/text</url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Any solution to this one??

Comment: Just don't use any character that will be percent encoded can't be accepted as the answer. 

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact problem. Change your artifact id to something like "SimpleWebApp" (note that I took out the '-') and it works. For what I wanted to do, it was not worth finding out the exact reason why this would not work. I don't think it is jersey, but something about tomcat.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp \
                -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
                -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=SimpleWebapp -Dpackage=com.example \
                -DarchetypeVersion=2.22.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears jetty 9.4 standard encodes request.getContextPath(), see [Jetty 9.4 ServletContextHandler.setContextPath behavior or Request data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715446/jetty-9-4-servletcontexthandler-setcontextpath-behavior-or-request-data-change) .

And debugging jersey (version 2.30.1 -> 2.35 ) ServletContainer I find the following code (line 94+):

```
        String decodedBasePath = request.getContextPath() + servletPath + "/";
        String encodedBasePath = UriComponent.encode(decodedBasePath, Type.PATH);
        if (!decodedBasePath.equals(encodedBasePath)) {
            this.setResponseForInvalidUri(response, new ProcessingException("The servlet context path and/or the servlet path contain characters that are percent encoded"));
        } else {
```

So Jersey does not expect request.getContextPath() to be encoded.

I.e. it appears jersey needs upgrading to adjust to the new jetty 9.4 behaviour!

Until then we won't be able to have e.g. spaces in URL handled as it used to...