# Jetty 9.4 ServletContextHandler.setContextPath behavior or Request data change

Tags: java, servlets, jetty-9

I have an a jetty server that is configured programmatically.  I upgraded from 9.3.7 to 9.4.7 and now context paths with spaces no longer work.

So servicePath="/Foo/Bar One Two" and requests have proper %20 replacing spaces. My log shows a request ""GET //localhost:8180/Foo/Bar%20One%20Two/foobar HTTP/1.1".

My server has two identical servlets with the only difference being the context path.

What has changed? It could be in the way the resource path is presented to the servlet.

My code specifying the context path looks like:

```
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder( ... );
ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
handler.setContextPath( servicePath );
handler.setVirtualHosts( connectors );
handler.addServlet( holder, "/*" );
contextHandlers.addHandler( handler );
```

So now request org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request has URL info that is encoded when it wasn't before.

1. Is the URL (originalURI) in request org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request guaranteed to be fully encoded no matter what?
2. Clearly ServletContextHandler.setContextPath() accepts unencoded paths.  Does it accept both?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like request.getContextPath() now returns an encoded path.  Is this guaranteed?

Answer (score 0):

I determined that Jetty 9.4 changed the way request.getContextPath() responds.  It now appears to return an encoded path.

Note experimentation shows ServletContextHandler.setContextPath() accepts an unencoded path.